# config.xml file of Magento extension

Tags: xml, magento

I got the below code in a `config.xml` file of a Magento extension.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <brandlogo>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mconnect_Brandlogo</module>
                <frontName>brandlogo</frontName>
            </args>
        </brandlogo>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

I would like to know what the `<frontName>` tag is?

Answer (score 3):

All Magento extensions that expose controller routes need to define a frontname. In this particular example, it's an **adminhtml** controller, and the frontname is "brandlogo".

This means that if you go to `/index.php/admin/brandlogo/index` the Magento admin router will route your request to the Mconnect_Brandlogo's IndexController, i.e. `Mconnect_Brandlogo_IndexController::indexAction`.

If the `<area>` was `frontend` rather than `admin`, this is how you would define frontend (customer facing) routes.

---

Please be aware that this way of configuring admin routes is **deprecated.** There were security issues found with it (such as that you could type in "yourstore.com/brandlogo" and be shown the admin login page), and have now been replaced with the "new way" of routing admin modules:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mconnect_Brandlogo before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mconnect_Brandlogo_Adminhtml</Mconnect_Brandlogo>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Using this configuration you'd also store your controllers under the Adminhtml folder of "controllers", e.g.:

```
# File: app/code/community/Mconnect/Brandlogo/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

class Mconnect_Brandlogo_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
   // ...
}
```

For more information, have a look at the ridiculousness that was caused by the [Magento SUPEE-6788 security patch last year](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788).

Comment: Thank you for the bit of trivia about the security patch :)